# Override ng-hide on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

On the process of trying to learn angularjs, I am creating a set of `div`s using `ng-repeat`. I have five `div`s in all. I am only displaying the first `div` using `$first`directive component.

```
<div class="container" ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="demoController">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="job in jobs" ng-hide="!$first">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      {{job}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button class="btn-primary btn-xs add" ng-click="showNext($event)" ng-hide="$last">Add</button>
      <button class="btn-primary btn-xs delete" style="display: none;">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That works.

Now, each div has two buttons, Add and Delete. When I click add I want to hide the add button and delete button of the current row and open the next row. So I wrote,

```
$scope.showNext = function(evt) {
  var elm = evt.target;
  $(elm).hide();
  $(elm).next().hide();
  $(elm).closest("div.row").next().slideDown();
};
```

This is not working as `ng-hide` is overriding my `slideDown`. What is the angularjs way of doing it?

Also I would like the delete button only on the `$last` *visible* row && `!first`. How to find last visible row in ng-repeat?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/u4penpxw/

Comment: I think the cleaner way is to move the two methods (`showNext`, `hideThis`) to a directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't manipulate the DOM with things like `$(elm).hide();`, you should use `ng-class=` to let Angular add classes that hide or show the elements. If you switch your `ng-repeat` to `ng-repeat="job in jobs track by $index"`, you could write something like that in your `showNext()`-function:

```
 $scope.showNext = function(index) {
      $scope.currentJob = $scope.jobs[index]
 }
```

and call it like `ng-click="showNext($index)` - of course you'd need to do some refactoring as well. But then you could write something like `ng-class="{hidden: (job == currentJob}"` to hide all buttons except in the current row.

There's a lot of good thoughts in this q&a: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: I added a sketch of how you could move this closer to the Angular spirit.

Comment: angularjs is really amazing. http://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/p1u06h12/ thanks a ton